# I am looking for the name of this font

Tags: typography, font-identification

I would be very grateful if someone can tell me the name of this font:

[image]
It´s very similar to ITC Kristen but not the same. I have spent time looking for it in google but I haven´t found it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD - it would be good if you could tell us what resources you have tried. There is a list here, and it will help everyone to save time: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: Unfortunately WhatTheFont doesn't do very well with this, even with the distinctive ***y*** and ***g***.

Comment: Thank all of you (sorry my bad english). I think i´ve found the font. The name is "She Paints Me Blue".

Comment: Looks like that is a perfect match; it would be good if you answer your own question in the "answer"field, and then checkmark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yay @user20100 - good find! Judging from the (albeit quite blurry) reference image, it looks like a minimal stroke has been applied to make the font slightly heavier/bolder.  
Oh, and here's a link for all those stumbling across this: http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=she+paints+me+blue&text=Alquiler+integral&af=on&psize=l

Answer (score 3):

The font is called [She paints me blue](http://www.dafont.com/she-paints-me-blue.font?text=Alquiler%20de%20castillos)

[image]

Comment: Just seen you found it already :)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what the font is, it's pretty generic, i looks like you could find it in Dafonts handwriting section http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603

here's a tool i've used before with good results in identifying typefaces,

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/